# How would you illustrate this in a report to a client?

Tags: qgis, reports

The objectives are simple: They're adding a train station and the goal is to display how far you could get within 30 minutes before and after the new station is built. In this map that I'm working on here the circle size is calculated like this(all attributes with cost above 30 is removed, if there's time life when you get to a station we assume walking at 6 km/h for the remaining time and a limit at 20 minutes to prevent the circles from getting to big at origin.

Without the zoom layer the last circle is impossible to see since the size is really small. Any other good suggestions on how to illustrate this?

```
case when "cost" < 10
then
20*100*2
else
(30-"cost")*100*2
END
```

Green = Nothing's changed
Yellow = Discontinued public transport zone.
Blue = New public transport zone.

How would you solve this with only one map? Other solutions then mine wanted!

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more to what the client needs or is wanting to be shown?

Comment: 6 km/h straight line walking is quite fast, isn't it?

Comment: 6 km/h might be to fast yes.. But I don't think it's that relevant since it's an overview. Even if I would set it to 4 km/h I'm not sure I would notice a big differance with this zoom..? What speed would you use?

Answer (score 2):

You could display isochrones instead. That way, it's possible to display multiple thresholds (instead of just the one 20 min threshold in your example). Additionally, the last stop which was only visible in a detail map will also become visible in the main map as a center of isochrones.

Since you seem to want to show a before-and-after comparison, you could overlay the two sets of isochrones and then color the areas depending on whether the situation got better or worse.

[image]

Comment: Thats a good solution. I used your example on my car analysis over the same area. But it didn't turn out so great with busses and rail since there is very few buss lines and only one train connection.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this(would love your feedback if you think of something):

30 minutes of travel time with public transportation
[image]

120 minutes of travel time with public transportation:
[image]

Driving at the correct speed limits with a car:
[image]

And this is where all the measurements started from: (500 meter buffer from buss stops and 1000 meters from a train station)

[image]